# How do I make it so that you can't @everyone with an echo command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I want to add a way so that you cannot ping roles with the echo command. The only way I can think of is to check if 'content' starts with @ then it just responds with a message saying no, how can I do that?

```
@client.command()
async def echo(ctx, *, content:str):
    await ctx.send(content)
    print("Echo command works")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can control pings in a message we send with allowed_mentions,

```py
allowed_mentions = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone=False) 
await ctx.send(content, allowed_mentions=allowed_mentions)
```

This will successfully send the echo, even if there is an everyone ping, but will not ping everyone. If you want to reply to the user saying `No`, we have to check for mentions and reply.

```py
mentions = ctx.message.role_mentions
if any([mention.is_default() for mention in mentions]): # there is an everyone mention
    return await ctx.send('No')
else:
    # do stuff
```

### References:

- [`Messagable.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)
- [AllowedMentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.AllowedMentions.everyone)
- [`Message.role_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20mentions#discord.Message.role_mentions)
- [`is_default`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20mentions#discord.Role.is_default)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `character in string` like so:

```
@client.command()
async def echo(ctx, *, content:str):
    if "@" in content:
        return await ctx.send("No")
    await ctx.send(content)
    print("Echo command works")
```

Comment: I think that will not send anything even if there is no pings, even if i just use `@` somewhere, wouldn't recommend doing this